# Google drive api. Через какое то время Google отзывает токен

Tags: python, google-drive, google-console

столкнулся с такой проблемой: У меня на Raspberry pi стоит rclone(монтирует диск и копирует данные), к этой программе подключен google drivr api. Все работало хорошо в течении какого то времени, спустя какое-то время, одна из всех Raspberry сказала что токен отозван или недействителен, и перестала работать. Устройство было 3 штуки, и по очереди они переставали работать. Заходил в Гугл консоль, там все в порядке. С чем эта может быть связано ?

Comment: Ну, у токенов есть определённый срок годности, наверное?

Answer (score 1):

Авторизация Google Drive API по OAuth 2.0 (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk?hl=ru), который имеет 2 токена: "access_token" и "refresh_token". "access_token" живет не долго, для того что бы его обновить используется "refresh_token".

Как заставить это работать описано в оф.доке. Там же есть пример - https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python?hl=ru#step_2_configure_the_sample

Answer (score 1):

Гугл отзывает токен примерно через час. Точное время указано в поле *expiry*.

Проверить, действителен ли еще токен не натыкаясь на ошибку, можно так:

```
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
# credentials - объект авторизации который был получен в процессе запроса
# авторизации или ч/з Credentials.from_authorized_user_file
isValid = credentials.valid # это проверяет передан ли токен и не просрочен ли он по *expiry*
```

Получить новый токен без запроса новой авторизации, можно выполнив запрос:

```
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from requests import post

r = post('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
        headers={'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        data={
             'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
             'client_id': credentials.client_id,
             'client_secret': credentials.client_secret,
             'refresh_token': credentials.refresh_token
       })
```

В ответе должен быть новый *access_token*, а так же указание на срок его действия в секундах *expires_in* или сообщение об ошибке в *error_description* и *error*.

Ссылка на [документацию](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2).